# How to get rid of this settingwithcopy warning in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
urb_pop_reader = pd.read_csv('world_ind_pop_data.csv', chunksize=1000)
df_urb_pop = next(urb_pop_reader)
df_pop_ceb = df_urb_pop[df_urb_pop['CountryCode'] == 'CEB']
pops = zip(df_pop_ceb['Total Population'], 
       df_pop_ceb['Urban population (% of total)'])
pops_list = list(pops)

df_pop_ceb['Total Urban Population'] = [int(i[0] * i[1] *0.01) for i in pops_list]

df_pop_ceb.plot(kind='scatter', x='Year', y='Total Urban Population')
plt.show()
```

I get this :
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

How can i fix it?

Comment: Try `df_pop_ceb.loc[:,'Total Urban Population'] = [int(i[0] * i[1] *0.01) for i in pops_list]`. This is what the error message suggests.

Comment: Perhaps `df_pop_ceb = df_urb_pop[df_urb_pop['CountryCode'] == 'CEB'].copy()`  so that futher changes to this df don't mess w/the original.